# Change ID reference to this so that the function an be used on another div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, this

I have a function that is bound to an ID right now and want to have it be used on different ID's as well without having to rewrite the function for each ID. Would I use 'this' to do that?

Current:

```
$('#myID .myClass').swipe({
    swipeStatus : swipeStatus,
    allowPageScroll:"vertical"
});
```

Would this work:

```
$((this)+'.manage-accounts-account-name').swipe({
    swipeStatus : swipeStatus,
    allowPageScroll:"vertical"
});
```

Comment: `$('#myID .myClass, #myID .manage-accounts-account-name').swipe({...` just join the selectors

Comment: No, using `this` here is incorrect.  Why not just give all the elements you want the same class (for example `swipe`), then do `$('.swipe').swipe({...});`.

Comment: That assumes all cases will use the same options.

Comment: It seems to be binding to another div region when I just use the class.

Comment: @isaacweathers Yes, thats the idea of using a single class. It will apply the code to all elements that match with one call rather than needing to loop over each id.

Answer (score 2):

Set the same class name to all the elements and initialize them from it. For example, using a class name `swippable`.

```
<div id="myID" class="swippable">...</div>
<div id="anotherID" class="swippable">...</div>
...
```

```
$(".swippable").swipe({
    swipeStatus : swipeStatus,
    allowPageScroll: "vertical"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Go simple:

```
function doSomething(selector)
{
    $(selector).swipe({
        swipeStatus : swipeStatus,
        allowPageScroll:"vertical"
    });
}
```

Then you can do:

```
doSomething("#myID .myClass");
doSomething(".other_selector");
```

Comment: Doesn't really look very simple!

Comment: But it is a named function. I always forget I have that option instead of anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` as the context.

```
$('.manage-accounts-account-name',this)
```

the above will select all `$('.manage-accounts-account-name')` that are contained within `$(this)`

alternatively, you could also do it like this:

```
$(this).find('.manage-accounts-account-name')
```